htmlspecialchars() default flags
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

flags...
The default is ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401.

But then below

When neither of ENT_COMPAT, ENT_QUOTES, ENT_NOQUOTES is present, the default is ENT_NOQUOTES.

And indeed if you don't pass any flag all quotes  are unascaped. This made me open to xss for a long time.
So, what does "The default is ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401" mean, why does it say it is default?

The default value when passing no $flags parameter is
ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401

The second part...

When neither of ENT_COMPAT, ENT_QUOTES, ENT_NOQUOTES is present, the default is ENT_NOQUOTES

is talking about what happens when you do pass a value but it contains neither ENT_COMPAT, ENT_QUOTES or ENT_NOQUOTES.
For example, passing no $flags parameter
$str = <<<_HTML
'single quotes'
"double quotes"
_HTML;

echo htmlspecialchars($str);

produces

&#039;single quotes&#039;
&quot;double quotes&quot;


Whereas passing a $flags parameter that has no quote controlling values defaults the quotes handling to ENT_NOQUOTES
htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_HTML5);


'single quotes'
"double quotes"


Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/hl2tk

True. It is just versions thing. It was changed not long ago, see my reply.

That doesn't seem to reflect what you're asking in your question though. You wanted to know about how each default was applied

I think your answer could be improved by also mentioning the change between versions - if you expand your 3v4l demo with the "include EOL versions" option, you will see that prior to 8.1, the double quotes were escaped by default, but the single quotes left as-is. While hopefully not many people are using those EOL versions, that's a recent enough change that a lot of people will still encounter it.

@IMSoP but that's not the question. Feel free to add your own answer if you think it's relevant

found it:

8.1.0 flags changed from ENT_COMPAT to ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401.

my version is below 8.1.0.
I guess when I added code long ago I just missed those flags.
